# How to remove the first array element in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

How do I remove the first array item from `holidayArray` in the following code:

```
@foreach (var item in holidayArray)
{
   <p>@item</p>                
}
```

Comment: `holidayArray.Skip(1)`

Answer (score 3):

Simply [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) that first item:

```
@foreach (var item in holidayArray.Skip(1))
{
     <p>@item</p>                
}
```

this will ignore 1 item from the start.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for display in page, then you can ignore the first element by this way

```
@foreach (var (item, index) in holidayArray.Select((x,i) => (x, i)))
{
   if (index > 0) {
   @: <p>@item</p> 
   }               
}
```